# R how to merge different columns of data frame in one

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data frame in R which looks like this

```
data
x1  x2  x3a x3b x3c x3d x4
A   43  0   0   0   1   P
B   23  0   1   0   0   Q
C   11  0   0   0   0   R 
D   66  0   0   1   0   S
```

Now I want to merge columns `x3a, x3b, x3c, x3d` to single column. The expected single column will contain column number having value 1 among `x3a,x3b,x3c,x3d`. The value should be numbered `(x3a=1,x3b=2,x3c=3,x3d=4)`. Expect result will be like following

```
x3
[1] 4    2    0    3
```

I tried `reshape()` function but could not get what I actually wanted

```
q<-data[,3:6]
r<-reshape(q,varying=c("x3a","x3b","x3c","x3d"),v.names="x3",direction="long",times=c("x3a","x3b","x3c","x3d"))
final<-r[r$x3!=0,][,3]
```

But this did not give expected result. It missed out the value `0` between `2` and `3`:

```
final
[1]4    2    3
```

Comment: are the ones per row unique?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked:

```
data <- data.frame(
  x1 = c('A','B','C','D'),
  x2 = c(43,23,11,66),
  x3a = c(0,0,0,0),
  x3b = c(0,1,0,0),
  x3c = c(0,0,0,1),
  x3d = c(1,0,0,0),
  x4 = c('P','Q','R','S')
)
data$x3 <- as.matrix(data[,c('x3a','x3b','x3c','x3d')]) %*% c(1,2,3,4)
```

The result:

```
  x1 x2 x3a x3b x3c x3d x4 x3
1  A 43   0   0   0   1  P  4
2  B 23   0   1   0   0  Q  2
3  C 11   0   0   0   0  R  0
4  D 66   0   0   1   0  S  3
```

---

Chase made a comment that is relevant: What if `x3a ... x3d` are different than zero or one? You can use `ifelse()` to consider that scenario:

```
data$x3 <- as.matrix(ifelse(data[,c('x3a','x3b','x3c','x3d')] > 0, 1, 0)) %*% c(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: clever! NOTE that this assumes that the values in `x3a - x3d` are always going to be 1, which seems like a safe assumption in this case.

Comment: @Chase It's all I can figure with the data provided in the OP (indicator variables)... But a simple modification can be made to support any condition

Comment: Yeah, I agree - mainly just noting that for posterity / if the OPs data is different than what was indicated. Again, very clever solution!

Comment: What if there are more than one ones per row? and we have to chose any one of the columns containing 1?

Comment: @Prabhu then the result can't be unique. You must define a rule to deal with that scenario

Answer (score 5):

@Barrankas answer is very clever and also vectorized, here's a less clever/vectorized option

```
as.numeric(apply(data[, 3:6], 1, function(x) which(x == 1)))
## [1]  4  2 NA  3
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `row` and `col` indexing. Should be quick as you only assign once.

```
data$new <- 0
tmp <- data[3:6]==1
data$new[ row(tmp)[tmp] ] <- col(tmp)[tmp]

data

#  x1 x2 x3a x3b x3c x3d x4 new
#1  A 43   0   0   0   1  P   4
#2  B 23   0   1   0   0  Q   2
#3  C 11   0   0   0   0  R   0
#4  D 66   0   0   1   0  S   3
```

`tmp` can be changed to accommodate whatever logical comparison is required.

Comment: Finally, a use for `row()` and `col()` !!

Comment: @RichardScriven - very underused functions for this sort of task.

Comment: I usually always give them a try in the matrix indices but I always end up confused.  Haha

Answer (score 4):

Even if the question had received an optimal solution, I'd just add an answer based on the maybe not much known `max.col` function, that gives the column index of the maximum element of a row. In this case:

```
  data$x3 <-  max.col(data[,3:6])*as.logical(rowSums(data[,3:6]))
```

This call gives 0 when all the elements are 0s (as required) and the maximum index otherwise. It has the advantage that the values can be any. If there is a tie, `max.col` chooses a random column by default; you can set it also the first or the last maximum found.

Answer (score 1):

One more:  You can use `match` across the rows, with the `nomatch` argument set to zero

```
apply(df[-c(1,2,length(df))] == 1, 1, match, x = TRUE, nomatch = 0L)
# [1] 4 2 0 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use `unite` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) 

 dat1 <- data

 data$x3 <- unite(data[,3:6], x3, sep="") %>% #I could use starts_with("x3"), but it adds more characters
                mutate(x3 = sub("-\\d", "0", paste(gregexpr("[^0]", x3)))) #x3 is character column
 data
    x1 x2 x3a x3b x3c x3d x4 x3  
 #1  A 43   0   0   0   1  P  4
 #2  B 23   0   1   0   0  Q  2
 #3  C 11   0   0   0   0  R  0
 #4  D 66   0   0   1   0  S  3
```

Suppose, you have more than one match per row and value is other than 0

```
 dat1$x3c[2] <- 3
 dat1$x3 <- unite(dat1[,3:6], x3, sep="") %>% 
                      mutate(x3 = sub("-\\d", "0", paste(gregexpr("[^0]", x3))))


 dat1
 #  x1 x2 x3a x3b x3c x3d x4  x3
 #1  A 43   0   0   0   1  P   4
 #2  B 23   0   1   3   0  Q 2:3
 #3  C 11   0   0   0   0  R   0
 #4  D 66   0   0   1   0  S   3
```